# Plugin that will let me specify a number of image sizes?

Tags: plugins, images

I've designed a grid-based portfolio theme for a photographer; for each portfolio item, I need six different images, all of which have a fixed size. However, no two sizes are alike. Is there a WordPress plugin that will easily allow me to specify a number of different image sizes and choose easily between them when uploading photos? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) ? It allows you to create new custom thumbnail sizes for uploaded images.

If you need to create new thumbnails for previously uploaded images, use my [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.